# german umlaute are not displayed in terminal

Tags: locale, german

I have a file 'test.txt' with the following content: ä, ö, ü.
When I type

```
 cat test.txt
 �, �, �
```

What is wrong?
The system is running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I checked locales installed german support, but I can't get it working properly.

Comment: Maybe you did not install font? Which terminal do you use?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file (`file -i text.txt`)? And of the terminal (`echo $LANG`)?

Comment: I ssh into the ubuntu system.
`echo $LANG` outputs en_US.UTF-8.
On another machine the same file prints out correctly.